# Registering Environment Resources VMs behind a proxy

Tags: azure

I want to know what are **the only-needed** subdomain URLs by an azure-agent software when used to  run to register a VM as an **azure-devops environment resource**

the URLs found here are generic, and does not meet a least-privileged practice:

[Running agent behind a firewall or a proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#im-running-a-firewall-and-my-code-is-in-azure-repos-what-urls-does-the-agent-need-to-communicate-with)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install self-hosted agent or set up VM type env resource on a VM which is secured with a firewall or proxy server, you need add the domain URL "**`https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net`**" into the allowlist at least.

However, since different resources on Azure DevOps could be hosted on difference domain URLs or IP ranges, when you run pipeline jobs on the self-hosted agent to access these resources, you also need to add all the related domain URLs or IP ranges into the allowlist.

For more details, you can reference the document "[**Allowed IP addresses and domain URLs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4)".